# Force Imports in Apache Karaf

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf

I have bundle that deals mostly with interfaces and it uses a factory from a thrid party jar to get the instances for the interfaces it is using.
For example,

> my-bundle.jar has...

```
com.oth.itf.Intrface itf = Fctry.getInstance('ABC');
```

has the

```
imports-package for com.oth.itf
```

> third-party.jar has..

```
public static com.oth.itf.Intrface getInstance(String abc) {
   if (...) {
       return new com.oth.impl.ItfInstance();
   }
}
```

has the `exports-package for com.oth.itf and com.oth.impl`

Everything works fine and bundles also get deployed but the issue is that I am getting

> ClassNotFoundException for ItfInstance

on

> my-bundle

when the code gets executed.

I tried adding import-package for com.oth.impl but to no avail. Things started to work when I added a

> dummy declaration of com.oth.impl.ItfInstance

some where in my-bundle.jar. Looks like, Karaf gets the imports only if we explicitly use them. Is there a better way? Is there a way to force Karaf to import packages even if we don't use them explicitly?

Comment: No that's not how imports work in OSGi. An import is an import, there's no "force" option. It's impossible to tell what's really going wrong in your example because there are no manifests posted.

Comment: Well I don't have a sample but I can tell you that pom.xml has the import-package for a particular package but manifest does not because the package has not been explicitly been used in the code.

Comment: If the manifest doesn't import the package then the package is not imported. Period. How did the manifest end up that way? Who knows. It's a build problem so you would have to give details of the build system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neil is right, if it's not used in the code it can't be imported. With Karaf you have the possibility to help. With the command *bundle:dynamic-import* you can add a dynamical import to the bundle on run-time. With this you're able to find the actually needed imports via *bundle:headers* you'll find the imported packages of this bundle. Take those and add those missing imports to your manifest generation and your're set.

Answer (score 0):

If you doesn't has **bundle:** option, uses this **dev:** command:

```
dev:dynamic-import <BundleID>
```

This allows Karaf import dependencies on runtime.